# How to Concatenate Two Extracted Columns?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to display the total time Days & hours someone has checked in.

The code below creates the variables in seperate columns with no identifiers apart from the column header. I can also create a column which displays the total hours.

```
select id, fname, lname, othertablevariable,
extract(day from diff) Days,
extract(hour from diff) Hours
from(
select id, fname, lname, othertablevariable,
(CAST(checkout as timestamp)-CAST(checkin as timestampe)) diff
from table t1, table t2
where t1.id=t2.id);
```

The output comes out as:

```
id fname lname days hours
```

However, I want the days column and hours column to be a single column.

Ideally it could display as `4 days 3 hours`. Is this possible?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed. (

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use inner query in order to achieve it. Check the answer below:

```
select id, ..., Days || Hours ConcatenatedColumn
from
(
    select id, fname, lname, othertablevariable,
    extract(day from diff) Days,
    extract(hour from diff) Hours
    from(
    select id, fname, lname, othertablevariable,
    (CAST(checkout as timestamp)-CAST(checkin as timestampe)) diff
    from table t1, table t2
    where t1.id=t2.id)
)
```

Comment: This is looking good. 
Now i've written 
select id, ...., Days || ' Days ' || Hours ConcatenatedColumn

How do I make the column display data e.g.:
1 Days 3 hours

(I can only get it to say 1 Days Hours 3)

Comment: Nevermind I got it Days ||' Days ' ||Hours||' Hours ' time
:) Thanks  alot!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by using [`CONCAT()`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/concat.php) function:

```
select id, fname, lname, othertablevariable,
       CONCAT(extract(day from diff), ' days ', extract(hour from diff), ' hours') AS dayshours
from (
....
```

The result will be `X days Y hours`